# Keras/Tensorflow - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rescale'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In the following line of code:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rescale'
```

Provided that I'm using `Keras v.1.0.3` with a Tensorflow backend. I'm using TensorFlow `v.1.0.0`.

Using the latest version of Keras will cause me the issue below, which is why I'm avoiding using the latest version:

```
KeyError: "Can't open attribute (Can't locate attribute: 'nb_layers')"
```

The latter issue seems to be related to this code snippet:

```
# load VGG16 weights
    f = h5py.File(weights_path)

    for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
        if k >= len(model.layers):
            break
        g = f['layer_{}'.format(k)]
        weights = [g['param_{}'.format(p)] for p in range(g.attrs['nb_params'])]
        model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)

    f.close()
    print('Model loaded.')
```

How can I solve this `rescale` issue, or even the latter issue if that would work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the latest Keras and Tensorflow versions solved the issue.